# what is difference between l and ls commands

Tags: command-line, command

`ls` command shows the following :

`a  code  controller.js  mani  sparat  this  ubuntu.gif`

`l` command the shows similar to that :

`a/  code/  controller.js  mani/  sparat/  this/  ubuntu.gif`

What is difference between them ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`l` is probably a shell alias. On my Ubuntu 14.04 by default it is :

```
alias l='ls -CF'
```

From the `man ls page`, these flags mean :

```
 -C  list entries by columns
 -F, --classify
          append indicator (one of */=>@|) to entries
```

Type `alias l` to find out what actually the `l` command is calling.